# Cannot find Trigger target... the target must appear before

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatemplate

I'm getting this warning:

Cannot find the Trigger target '`ErrandPropertiesGroupBox`'.  (The target must appear before any Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that use it.)

Here's the XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ErrandData" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate">
            <GroupBox>
                <GroupBox.Header>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <Label Content="Group #" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=df_groupOrder}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </GroupBox.Header>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=df_errands}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Name="label1" Content="{Binding Path=TypeName}" />
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ErrandPropertiesGroupBox" Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<WrapPanel Name="rootWrapPanel">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ErrandData}, Path=df_sequentialErrandGroup}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <GroupBox Name="ErrandPropertiesGroupBox" Header="Errand Properties" />
</WrapPanel>
```

How can I fix this? (There are related posts on google but I can't piece together the right solution from them.)

Answer (score 2):

A setter inside of a `DataTemplate` can only reference other controls inside of that `DataTemplate` (that's its `NameScope`). So as far as I'm aware, you can't do it the way you're trying to do it.

I was trying to figure out how it *could* work for you, but I'm confused by your code. It looks like you're trying to set the background of a `GroupBox`, which is outside of an `ItemsControl`, whenever any item inside of a `ListBox` (that is itself inside of a `StackPanel`) is selected?

That doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense to me. Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

**Edit:**

Based on your comment below, I think that I would be looking towards using the `ViewModel` for this purpose. Binding the `Visibility` of the `GroupBox` to your `ViewModel` and then updating that property in your `ViewModel` as the selections change. Then if you wanted to make other things visible or invisible based on the same thing, you'd just have to bind to that property, not mess around with `Triggers` and `Setters`.

Comment: Oh, right... I forgot about that... what I mean to do is show the groupbox when any item in the listbox is selected. Changing the background was just an earlier test.

Comment: @jessejuicer OK, based on that, I edited my answer to give my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

From our friend the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.targetname.aspx):

> You can set this property to the name of any element within the scope of where the setter collection (the collection that this setter is part of) is applied. This is typically a named element that is within the template that contains this setter.

Your target is outside of scope, you are not supposed to change external objects from within some DataTemplate.